# Toggling a Twitter Bootstrap (3.x) Modal using AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, angularjs-directive, modal-dialog

I've been trying to get a Bootstrap Model to be hidden on load, and then show it after clicking a button, but have been unsuccessful so far. I am pretty new to AngularJS so bear with me if I'm not doing this correctly. Here's what I've got so far:

Modal Angular Directive (modal.js):

```
angular.module('my.modal', ['modal.html'])
.directive('myModal', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        transclude: true,
        replace: false,
        templateUrl: 'modal.html',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            element.modal('hide')
            scope.toggleModal = function() {
                if (attrs.showModal === true) {
                    element.modal('hide')
                    attrs.showModal = false
                } else {
                    element.modal('show')
                    attrs.showModal = true
                }
            }
        }
    };
});
```

Modal Template (modal.html):

```
<div id="{{id}}" showModal="false" tabindex="-1">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h3 class="modal-title">I'm a modal!</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="content" ng-transclude></div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="showModal = false">Cancel</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And finally, the button to toggle the modal (index.html):

```
...
<my-modal>
    <p>Some content</p>
</my-modal>
<button class="btn btn-default" type="button" ng-click="toggleModal()">Toggle me!</button>
...
```

All this does is show the modal on page load (between my header and all the other content, so it's not floating above anything) and the toggle button does not work.

Comment: If you're able to use another library I'd suggest looking at [UI Bootstrap](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/). It provides Bootstrap directives and services for you.

Comment: showModal is constant and never change. Try using `ng-show="showModal"`.

Comment: I've thought about using UI Bootstrap, but then I couldn't think of a way of doing transclusion. Any thoughts on that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to get it working by using the Bootstrap 3 Modal properties and dynamically changing styling and classes of the modal directive based on it's show or hide state, **though there are no animations**:

Modal Angular Directive (modal.js):

```
angular.module('my.modal', ['modal.html'])
.directive('myModal', [function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        transclude: true,
        replace: false,
        templateUrl: 'modal.html',
        controller: 'ModalCtrl',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            if (attrs.title === undefined) {
                scope.title = 'Modal Title Placeholder';
            } else {
                scope.title = attrs.title;
            }

            scope.$watch('showModal', function (value) {
                if (value) {
                    scope.displayStyle = 'block';
                    scope.modalFadeIn = 'in';
                } else {
                    scope.displayStyle = 'none';
                    scope.modalFadeIn = '';
                }
            });
        }
    };
}).controller('ModalCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.toggleModal = function() {
        $scope.showModal = !$scope.showModal;
    };

    $scope.$open = function() {
        $scope.showModal = true;
    };

    $scope.$close = function() {
        $scope.showModal = false;
    };
});
```

Modal Template (modal.html):

```
<div role="dialog" tabindex="-1" class="modal fade" ng-init="showModal = false" ng-show="showModal" ng-style="{display: displayStyle}" ng-class="modalFadeIn">
    <div class="modal-backdrop fade in" style="height: 100%"> </div>
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h3 class="modal-title">{{title}}</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="content" ng-transclude></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The call to open the  modal can be done using the open or toggleModal function. A custom button needs to be placed in the modal to close the modal.